# Mostrar mas de una imagen en carousel laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-carousel, carrusel

Hola a todos como estan: resulta que estoy trabajando un carousel el cual muestro imagenes que estan almacenadas en mi proyecto, y me funciona pero tengo el problema que solo me muestra una imagen, lo que necesito es que me muestre 3 imagenes, luego rote y me muestre 3 mas y asi consecutivamente, pero solo logro mostrar de a una imagen en cada vuelta del carousel...

En el controlador tengo definido asi:

```
$productos = Producto::latest('id')->paginate(3);

        return view('index', compact('posts', 'productos'));
```

y en la vista blade el codigo que tengo para el carousel:

```
  <div id="carouselProductos" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-indicators">
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                  <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
                  </div>

                    @foreach($productos as $producto)
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img src="{{asset($producto->url_imagen_portada)}}">
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                  </div>
    {{--               <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
                  </div> --}}
                </div>
              <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselProductos" data-bs-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Anterior</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselProductos" data-bs-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="visually-hidden">Siguiente</span>
                </button>
```

Una imagen de como se ve (en rojo lo que quiero obtener, o sea las otras 2 imagenes)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos a todos

Comment: Buen día, si haces `dd($productos)` en el controlador, justo antes del `return` puedes ver más de un producto en tu arreglo? Las imágenes están todas guardadas en la misma ruta? La ruta que obtienes de tu base de datos es correcta?

Comment: Hola buenos dias, las imagenes estan todas en la misma ruta, de hecho si muestro las imagenes de forma individual se cargan todas, el problema es al querer mostrar mas de una en cada fila del carousel....

Comment: funciona el carousel pero de a una imagen solamente, yo lo que necesito es que se muestren 3 iamgenes, luego rote a la proxima fila y se muestren 3 mas y asi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Encontré un [tutorial](https://codingyaar.com/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-items-increment-by-1/) para hacer un carrusel con múltiples `items`

También encontré una forma que tal vez te pueda servir

El problema que tienes es que estas haciendo un `foreach` en el `div` que es el `item` del carrusel, pero lo que necesitas es poner 3 imágenes dentro del mismo `item` y de esa forma mostrar 3 imágenes al mismo tiempo

El método que te voy a mostrar no es perfecto (Se me acaba de ocurrir) así que tendrás que adaptar las fórmulas

Debes reemplazar tu `foreach`, actualmente lo tienes así:

```
@foreach($productos as $producto)
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{asset($producto->url_imagen_portada)}}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Lo que vamos a hacer es iterar en las páginas que obtienes del método `paginate()` y luego iterar en los productos de cada página. Además vamos a utilizar clases de bootstrap para mostrar los elementos de forma correcta

```
@foreach(range(1, $productos->lastPage()) as $i)
    <div class="carousel-item d-flex row">
        @foreach(range(1, $productos->count()) as $j)
            <div class="col">
                <img src="{{asset($productos[(($i-1)*3)+$j]->url_imagen_portada)}}">
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Explicación:

En laravel no es posible utilizar el `paginator` para iterar en las páginas por lo que creamos un rango del total de páginas y lo utilizamos en el primer `foreach`. Esto nos va a dar un rango de 1 a ultimaPágina.

```
@foreach(range(1, $productos->lastPage()) as $i)
```

Como deseas utilizar múltiples elementos dentro de un `carousel-item` creamos el `div` en este nivel, es decir, en lo que vendría siendo el número de página

Dentro de la "página" que es el `carousel-item` necesitas X número de imágenes (Esto viene según lo que pongas en el `paginator`), en tu caso es 3

El método `count()` nos devuelve el total de elementos por página. Entonces creamos un rango de 1 al total de elementos por página y hacemos un `for` para crear las imágenes

```
@foreach(range(1, $productos->count()) as $j)
```

Ahora, para crear las imágenes necesitamos decirle a cada una el número de elemento que tiene dentro de `$productos` por lo que hacemos la siguiente operación

```
(($i-1)*3)+$j
```

Esto quiere decir:

```
$i es el número de página
$j es el número de elemento dentro de una página
```

Entonces para obtener el índice de los elementos de la primera página la formula nos daría los siguientes resultados con `$i = 1` y `$j` tomando valores de 1 a 3

```
(($i-1)*3)+$j = x
((1-1)*3)+1 = 1
((1-1)*3)+2 = 2
((1-1)*3)+3 = 3
```

Para la segunda página, es decir, con `$i = 2` y `$j` tomando valores de 1 a 3

```
(($i-1)*3)+$j = x
((2-1)*3)+1 = 4
((2-1)*3)+2 = 5
((2-1)*3)+3 = 6
```

Y así sucesivamente para todas las páginas

Esto te va a funcionar siempre y cuando el número de productos sea múltiplo de 3. Si el número de productos puede ser un valor que no sea múltiplo de 3 tendrías que modificar la fórmula o utilizar el método indicado en el tutorial que mencioné arriba

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda, entiendo lo que me comentas, pero al intentar ejecutar me salta error: Trying to get property 'url_imagen_portada' of non-object